# Rails 5.1 CORS - how to set different origins for different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, rack-cors

I am using the rack-cors gem with a Rail 5.1 API.

I have the following initializer as per the documentation:

config/initializers/cors.rb

```
module Api
  Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins ['http://localhost:4200','https://app.mydomain.com/']

      resource '*',
        headers: :any,
        :expose  => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],        
        methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
    end
  end
end
```

However, this means that when deployed to production my api will accept requests from any `localhost:4200` origin.

How can I separate these settings out so that different environments can have different allowed origins?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a few different options. One is to use `secrets.yml` file. There you can define different values per environment, let's say:

```
development:
  allowed_origins:
    - http://localhost:4200

production:
  allowed_origins:
    - http://productionurl1.com
    - http://productionurl2.com
```

Then in your configuration file you can do

```
module Api
  Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins Rails.application.secrets.allowed_origins
    end
  end
end
```

Another option (taken from the comments) is to use the environment files, eg:

development.rb

```
config.allowed_cors_origins = ["http://localhost:4200"]
```

Then in the `cors.rb` initializer you can do:

```
Rails.application.config.allowed_cors_origins
```

(since initializer will be called after the environment config file, this should work).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. You mentioned other options - how would you use the already existing environment files? Surely that would be preferable, since these are environment related settings?

Comment: If you want to use the environment config file, you can just write something like `config.allowed_cors_origins = ["http://localhost:4200"]` in `development.rb` file, and then in the `cors.rb` initializer you can do `origins Rails.application.config.allowed_cors_origins` - since initializer will be called after the environment config file, this should work.

Comment: The second option worked for me. I was using figaro gem for the environment variables, it kept throwing errors. setting the allowed origins on production/development.rb worked well though

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using rails 5.2, `secrets.yml` has been changed and now we need to use credentials. In order to use that, we need to edit `config/credentials.yml.enc`

First, run the command `EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit` (using the editor of your choosing). Then, add the origins as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49985771/1028679) suggests:

```
development:
  allowed_origins:
   - http://localhost:4200

production:
  allowed_origins:
   - http://productionurl1.com
   - http://productionurl2.com
```

Save the file. Now the allowed origins variables will be in the encrypted file. And then in the cors initializer (in my case it was in application.rb)

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:allowed_origins]
    resource '*',
    headers: :any,
    expose: ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
    methods: [:get, :post, :options, :delete, :put]
  end
end
```